# Merge two sorted lists

Tags: python, list, merge

Hello I want to ask why when I run this code below the `arr` didn't change it's value

```
def merge(arr, left, middle, right):
    newArr = []
    leftCounter = 0
    rightCounter = middle + 1
    while leftCounter <= middle and rightCounter <= right:
        if arr[leftCounter] < arr[rightCounter]:
            newArr.append(arr[leftCounter])
            leftCounter += 1
        else:
            newArr.append(arr[rightCounter])
            rightCounter += 1
    while leftCounter <= middle:
        newArr.append(arr[leftCounter])
        leftCounter += 1
    while rightCounter <= right:
        newArrCounter.append(arr[rightCounter])
        rightCounter += 1
    arr = newArr



def main():
    arr = [1, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6]
    merge(arr, 0, 2, 5)
    print(arr)
```

result of this is [1, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6]

thanks

Comment: For the record, this function is part of the standard library, as [`heapq.merge()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge).

Answer (score 0):

Because of variables inside the functions has local scope.you can return `arr` in your function and assign the function result to a variable, add `return arr` at the trailing of your function:

```
def main():
    arr = [1, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6]
    new=merge(arr, 0, 2, 5)
    print(new)
```

But *note* that changing a mutable object inside the function may impact the caller! but in this case you have assign `newArr` to `arr` at the end `arr = newArr` and then you do not change the arr,for example see the following example :

```
>>> def a(arr):
...   arr = [3,4]
>>> x=[5]
>>> a(x)
>>> x
[5]
>>> def a(arr):
...   arr+= [3,4]
... 
>>> a(x)
>>> x
[5, 3, 4]
```

On first state we have assigned a new object to name `arr` so python will crate an local variable in the local namespace of function `a`! but in second case we have changed the name `arr` and as `arr` is a mutable object python doesn't create a new object, instead it change the name `arr` globally!

Or you can initial `newArr` as global and then you can print it in main function :

```
def merge(arr, left, middle, right):
    global newArr
    newArr = []
    leftCounter = 0
    rightCounter = middle + 1
    while leftCounter <= middle and rightCounter <= right:
        if arr[leftCounter] < arr[rightCounter]:
            newArr.append(arr[leftCounter])
            leftCounter += 1
        else:
            newArr.append(arr[rightCounter])
            rightCounter += 1
    while leftCounter <= middle:
        newArr.append(arr[leftCounter])
        leftCounter += 1
    while rightCounter <= right:
        newArrCounter.append(arr[rightCounter])
        rightCounter += 1
    arr = newArr

def main():
    arr = [1, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6]
    merge(arr, 0, 2, 5)
    print(newArr)
```

Comment: but when I try to do this arr[3] = 5 inside merge function the arr get changed globally why? your code is wrong function didn't return anything !

Comment: @user3216932 its difference its because that `arr` is a mutable object and changing a mutable object inside the function may impact the caller!

Comment: than cant i mutate it to be = newArr ?

Comment: @user3216932 you can use `global` key word! or `return` it

Answer (score 0):

Simply, when you pass `arr` to the function, it is referencing a list in memory, but its *not the same reference* as `arr` outside the function (even though they refer to the same object). In the function, when you have

```
arr = newArr
```

Essentially you have the function scope reference point to the new object, but not the reference outside of the function.

http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/

if you *mutate* `arr` within the function, since they refer to the same object, the reference outside the function will still refer to the mutated object.